# Persist an async jquery call to WCF between pages

Tags: jquery, wcf, asynchronous

I was asked to implement a notification system like Facebook's.
I created a WCF service and am calling it through jquery. I have looked everywhere and I'm very surprised I have not found any one asking this (Maybe I'm just missing the point totally): What happens if the client moves to another page while the WCF service is doing its thing?

This particular WCF service might take several seconds to return a result, since it queries several different data sources. The user moving to a new page in this time is a real possibility.
The issue is not only that the result will not return to the appropriate user, but also the service will be called again.

I was going through all the methods to persist the call (not the call itself, but rather the fact that it was even made) like save a flag in session state, write a cookie, viewstate, etc. but I'm thinking that WCF / jquery must have some way of resolving this issue.

Please help me see what I'm missing.
Thank you!

**Edit:** Maybe I was a bit unclear. I am looking for something built in to WCF, in case I missed it or maybe some king of known pattern. I am not looking for ways to not navigate away from the page!

Comment: That's why people attach 'Do you want to leave the page?' dialog boxes to window.onunload

Comment: That's not even an option. The client would rather throw out notifications altogether than ask the user for permission each time they want to navigate away. p.s. and that's why people leave sites and never come back.